# How to format pdf or excel with itextsharper from Asp.net Control

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate report in pdf,excel format. I have used asp.net repeater control for data binding. I am using iTextSharp. I rendered, page control to pdf and excel format.

Code:

```
StringWriter sw2 = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw2 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw2);
this.rptBillReport.RenderControl(hw2);

Paragraph report = new Paragraph();
using (StringReader sr2 = new StringReader(sw2.ToString()))
{
    //Parse and get a collection of elements
    List<IElement> elements2 = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr2, null);
    foreach (IElement val2 in elements2)
    {
        //Add those elements to the paragraph
        report.Add(val2);
    }
}

Document pdfDoc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4,
                         30f, 30f, 30f, 0.0f);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
//htmlparser.Parse(sr);

pdfDoc.Add(report);

pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

My Question here is:
How do I format the report, adding border and other style in both pdf and excel? It is not showing on my current report.

Comment: You have to remove css class and give inline style in html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,
I added stylesheet like this:

```
 StyleSheet styles= new StyleSheet();
            styles.LoadTagStyle("#rptBillReport", "height", "30px");
            styles.LoadTagStyle("#rptBillReport", "font-weight", "bold");
            styles.LoadTagStyle("#rptBillReport", "font-family", "Cambria");
            styles.LoadTagStyle("#rptBillReport", "font-size", "20px");
            styles.LoadTagStyle("#rptBillReport", "background-color", "white");

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(styles);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
```

It worked.